# Developing a php page and getting redirected to web not localhost?

Tags: php, apache

I'm developing a site locally on WAMP and I'm having an issue that I can't resolve where any .php page that I try and access on my localhost and I get redirected to the internet.

I can create an index.html file and apache seems to display that properly but none of my .php pages work/display correctly.

I have modified the hosts file on my PC and have added a virtual host to the apache http-vhosts.conf file.

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 hostname
```

vhsots file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/testsite/php"
ServerName domainnamehere

<Directory "c:/testsite/php">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone have any suggestions for what I've missed?

Comment: If `index.html` works fine, seems likely there's something in your code that's doing the redirecting.

Comment: Do you get to the index.html file when using the domain name in a browser or do you open it manually?

Answer (score 1):

First, i assume `domainnamehere` and `hostname` are the same

Also, in my WAMP projects, i've defined paths relative to WAMP instalation:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/testsite/php"
ServerName domainnamehere

<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/testsite/php">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Maybe it helps

Comment: Sorry for the delay...
http://localhost/index.html <- works fine
http://localhost/index.php <- redirects to internet
yes, sorry that was a typo... domainnamehere and hostname are the same

Comment: So the problem ultimately is in the coding of the PHP page: 
<?php virtual('/Connections/connect.php'); ?> I fixed it at the moment by using <?php requireonce('/Connections/XLShop.php'); ?>